# How to programmatically check, get and set touch settings in android phones?

Tags: android, touch

Is it possible to programmatically get the various touch settings in Android such as:

-> Dial pad touch tones

-> Touch sounds

-> Screen lock sound

-> Vibrate on touch

I have tried accessing the various constants in System.Settings, but I see no mention of constants for the touch settings. Can anyone provide me with info on the APIs or constants I could use for this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the following to check

**-> Dial pad touch tones:**

```
boolean isDtmfToneEnabled = Settings.System.getInt(contentResolver,
        Settings.System.DTMF_TONE_WHEN_DIALING, 1) != 0;
```

**-> Touch sounds:**

```
boolean isTouchSoundsEnabled = Settings.System.getInt(contentResolver,
        Settings.System.SOUND_EFFECTS_ENABLED, 1) != 0;
```

**-> Screen lock sound:**

```
boolean islockScreenSoundsEnabled = Settings.System.getInt(contentResolver,
        "lockscreen_sounds_enabled", 1) != 0;
```

**-> Vibrate on touch:**

```
boolean isVibrateOnTouchEnabled = Settings.System.getInt(contentResolver,
        Settings.System.HAPTIC_FEEDBACK_ENABLED, 1) != 0;
```

You can use [putInt()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html#putInt%28android.content.ContentResolver,%20java.lang.String,%20int%29) API to change their values. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot.

Comment: its not enable the switch when i set like this Settings.System.getInt(contentResolver,
        Settings.System.SOUND_EFFECTS_ENABLED, 1) it enable the touch sound but not change the switch .

Comment: @ozbek the question asks, how to enable touch settings programatically, but you answered something else i believe.

Comment: Your belief is futile, @SumitKumarSaha

Comment: Everything works as expected. Does anyone know about the "Charging sounds and vibration" setting?

Answer (score 0):

Disable vibration touch:

```
boolean isVibrateOnTouchEnabled = Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(),
                            Settings.System.HAPTIC_FEEDBACK_ENABLED, 1) != 0;
if(isVibrateOnTouchEnabled) {
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.HAPTIC_FEEDBACK_ENABLED, 0);
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Vibration touch Off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Disable Screen Lock Sound:**

```
boolean islockScreenSoundsEnabled = Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(),
                            "lockscreen_sounds_enabled", 1) != 0;
                  if(islockScreenSoundsEnabled) {
                      Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),"lockscreen_sounds_enabled", 0);
                  }
```